# Splitting a string from fputs

Tags: c, split, strtok, fputs

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   char str[60];
   char data[50];
   char * pch;

   /* opening file for reading */
   fp = fopen("DATAtest.txt" , "r");
   if(fp == NULL) {
      perror("Error opening file");
      return(-1);
   }
   if( fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL ) {
      /* writing content to stdout */
      //puts(str);
   }
if( fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL ) {
      /* writing content to stdout */
      puts(str);

printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
while (pch != NULL)
    {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
      }
       fclose(fp);
       return(0);
    }
```

Basically what it does is to open a file and extract the data from the second line. What it should do next (from the line: printf ("Splitting...)), is to split the text obtained into separate character. For example: i get the following text " 0 0 128 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; i would like to split it this way:

```
0 
0
128
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Sorry about the code i am just starting with this.

Comment: You have two `fgets` calls. What is the purpose of the first call (that likely discards the first line of the file) ?

Comment: This assumes that the first two lines in DATAtest.txt have fewer than 60 characters. (If the first line is longer than 60 characters, then only the first 59 characters will be grabbed.

Comment: Your program (albeit lacking `#include <string.h>`) does what you want with the given input - so what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main(){
     FILE *fp;
     char str[60] = " 0 0 128 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;";//from fgets
     char *data[50];//or char data[max number of parts][max of lengh of parts]
     char *pch;
     const char *delimiter = " ,.-;";
     int i, cnt = 0;

     printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);

     pch = strtok (str, delimiter);
     while (pch != NULL){
         //printf ("%s\n", pch);
         //strcpy(data[cnt++], pch);//by 2D array, Not necessary free.
         data[cnt++] = strdup(pch);//make clone. it's not standard function.
         pch = strtok (NULL, delimiter);
     }
     for(i = 0; i<cnt; ++i){
         printf("%s\n", data[i]);
         free(data[i]);//release
     }
     return(0);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show me the content of your file. I replaced your while loop with a for loop because it is more concise and easier to understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char str[60];
    char data[50];
    char * pch;

    /* opening file for reading */
    fp = fopen("DATAtest.txt" , "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return(-1);
    }
     if( fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL ) {
      /* writing content to stdout */
      //puts(str);
     }

    if( fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL ) {
        /* writing content to stdout */
        puts(str);

        printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
        for(pch = strtok(str, " ,.-"); pch != NULL; pch = strtok(NULL, " ,.-"))
        {
            puts(pch);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is his second line?

Comment: @JayElston I returned that line.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is how your `DATAtest.txt` file looks like:

```
abcd pqr strm
" 0 0 128 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
xyz abr
```

I have made minor changes in your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   FILE *fp;
   char str[60];
   char data[50];
   char * pch;

   /* opening file for reading */
   fp = fopen("DATAtest.txt" , "r");
   if(fp == NULL) {
      perror("Error opening file");
      return(-1);
   }
   if( fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL ) {
      /* writing content to stdout */
      //puts(str);
   }
   if( fgets (str, 60, fp)!=NULL ) 
   {
        /* writing content to stdout */
        puts(str);
        str[strlen(str)-1]='\0'; // Remove \n from str
        printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
        pch = strtok (str,"\" ,.-;"); //Mention required delimiters 
        while (pch != NULL)
        {
            printf ("%s\n",pch);
            pch = strtok (NULL, "\" ,.-;");//Mention required delimiters
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

**Output**

```
" 0 0 128 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;

Splitting string "" 0 0 128 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;" into tokens:
0
0
128
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```